# How to include attachments when cases are submitted via web-to-case to web-to-lead scenarios?

Tags: salesforce

How to attach one of more files when creating web-to-lead from the code. Solution should not be any of the following:

1. Visualforce pages in Force.com Sites
2. Using Force.com web services API implementation.

Answer (score 1):

[You can't](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332973&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1). Consider cross-posting this to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/, maybe somebody has a brillant idea.

[There's idea you can upvote, looks like they'll have something in Summer'22.](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrhfAAC) Until then you need VF page exposed as Site, Aura component exposed with Lightning Out or a proper API integration. Can you make-do with "InboundEmailHandler"? Body of email could be JSON or something, attachments you could save? 36 MB limit though.

Web-to-Case and Web-to-Lead support only simple forms. Normal HTTP way to mix forms and binary data is to use "[multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)" but Web-to-Case doesn't support it: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customizesupport_web_to_case_notes.htm&type=5

There are [tricks like upload the file somewhere else](http://www.susannelumme.com/salesforce-hack-web-to-lead-with-file-upload/) (another website you control) and just display link to it on the Lead... But it's not true file upload to SF.